# Resolve code duplication with polymorphism

Tags: c++

Suppose there is a base class, and two derived classes from it:

```
struct Derive1 : public Base
{
    func(TypeA arg)
    {
        // Common code part 1

        specificFunc(arg);

        // Common code part 2
    }

    specificFunc(TypeA arg)
    {
        // specific implementation
    }
};

struct Derive2 : public Base
{
    func(TypeB arg)
    {
        // Common code part 1

        specificFunc(arg);

        // Common code part 2
    }

    specificFunc(TypeB arg)
    {
        // specific implementation
    }
};
```

Both of the two derived classes have a method `func()` but with different type of arguments. The bodies of `func()` are almost the same, except that somewhere in the middle of the function, they call `specificFunc()` with different types as arguments. and `specificFunc()` of these two derived class have completely different implementations.

What would be a good design to get rid of the duplication of `Common code part 1` and `Common code part 2`?

Extracting `Common code part 1` and `Common code part 2` isn't an option as there are control logics inside `Func()`.

Comment: You may factor out `Common code part 1` and `Common code part 2`, e.g. in plain functions or base class member functions. The opposite would be a common function (template) for `func()` where you provide the `specificFunc` as argument.

Comment: Did that mean the common pre/post code did not depend on the function parameter?

Comment: @Klaus Yes that's correct. But the calling of `specificFunc()` is somewhere in a rather complicated control logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fact that both Derive1 and Derive2 inherit from Base. Maybe you can find a way to make "Common part 1" and "Common part 2" parts of Base.